# Auto Submit for Approval with Flow - nextApproverIds issue

Tags: approval-process

I have one approval process that has the Assigned Approver as Manually Chosen.
I want to create a flow to automatically submit the Opportunity to approval when certain criteria is met.
On the Process Build its not possible to set the nextApproverIds, so I tried with it and got this error:
[image]

So I'm trying with the Flow which I can select the Next Approver IDs, however its not allowing me to set the value that I want - which is supposed to be the Manager ID of the Opportunity's Owner.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Next Approver IDs is actually a list of Ids, but you can have only first element filled.
To fix the issue create a collection variable and add Record.Owner.Manager.Id to that collection, after that assign that collection to Next Approver IDs.

Comment: Seems to be on the right path however Ive created a Text collection variable which does not accept to add this value: {!$Record.Owner.Manager.Id}
Ive tried {!$Record.Owner.Manager.Id} + ''
{!$Record.Owner.Manager.Id}&''
{!$Record.Owner.Manager.Id}''

None worked... how to convert the ID to a string?

Comment: Just tried this {!$Record.Owner.Manager.Id}  and also didnt work - It has a space right after the }. Here is the error message: We can't save this record because the “Opportunity - Extension Requested” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. bad id 0052p00000AfG76AAF Error ID: 2023805675-121236 (-953294561)bad id 0052p00000AfG76AAF Error ID: 2023805675-121236 (-953294561)

Comment: Try adding {!$Record.Owner.ManagerId} instead of putting Manager.Id

Comment: Same issue, error is: Enter a valid value.

Comment: Seems like the problem isnt the way that I get the ID but on the conversion from the ID to a String

Comment: That should definitely not cause a problem. Check if you are using "add" operator when trying to add that id to text collection. Does some value get added to the collection when you debug that flow?

Comment: It was a bug in SF... its was not recognizing {!$Record.Owner.Manager.Id} as an ID and it was asking to provide a valid value... Ive reloaded the page and it worked..........

Answer (score 0):

Next Approver Ids field only accepts **Text collection variables**
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/flow-builder/flow-builder-create-variable